# Using common database for multiple developers in local environment gets slow in drupal 9

Tags: database, performance, drupal, drupal-9, slowdown

When use the common database to develop in local environment for multiple developers in one **Drupal 9** project is getting too slow. This issue occurs on Drupal sites only, others (**Wordpress, Laravel, Codeigniter and slim**) are working fine with the same database from the server and found that not an network and server issue.
In our scenario, we want to use **a common database for multiple developers in our local environment** **for a Drupal 9 project**. We may clear the cache frequently during the development process.Can you give me any suggestions for achieving this process?

Used the common database from host server to develop in local environment for multiple developers in one **Drupal 9** project. But it gets slow when loading (for ex. doing CRUD operation, cache clear and etc).

Could any one provide the suggestion to implement the common database for multiple developers in local environment Drupal sites?